# How to construct a IBM Quantum Experience circuit for the following state transformation?

Tags: circuit-construction, ibm-q-experience, hadamard

Please help me in building IBM Quantum Experience circuit for:
$$
M|0\rangle = \frac{1}{2}(|0\rangle+|1\rangle+|2\rangle+|3\rangle)
$$

Edit: Is it possible to make a circuit for a general transformation  $M|0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}|i\rangle$ acting on $\log m$ qubits initialized to $|0\rangle$?

Comment: Simply put Hadamard gates on two qubits and that's it.

Comment: @MartinVesely can we give circuit for a general transformation  $M|0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}|i\rangle$ by initializing $log~m$ qubits to $|0\rangle$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to EDIT in question:**

It is possible to prepeare a state

$$|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}|i\rangle,$$

where $m = 2^n$ and $n$ is a number of qubits, by application of operator $\otimes H ^{n} = H_{q_0} \otimes H_{q_1} \otimes \dots \otimes H_{q_{n-1}}$, i.e. Hadamard gate is applied on each qubit involved. As a results, you will get $n=\log{m}$ qubits in superposition described by uniform probability distribution. It is a generalization of construction provided in answer by *met927*

---

**EDIT:** based on comment by *Adam Levine*: *"what if for example $m=5$?"*

It that case you have to prepare entangled state and the approach is a little bit more intricated. For $m=5$ you have to prepare state (*I switched to more common convention with states expressed in binary numbers instead of decimal*):

$$
|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(|000\rangle + |001\rangle + |010\rangle+|011\rangle+|100\rangle),
$$

i.e. three qubits state where $|101\rangle$, $|110\rangle$ and $|111\rangle$ have zero probability.

To prepare an arbitrary state, you can employ approach presented in this article:
[Transformation of quantum states using uniformly controlled rotations](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0407010).

Based on the article, a circuit preparing state $|\psi\rangle$ is this:

[image: Circuit]

Here you can see results provided by IBM Q simulator:

[image]

Apparently, the circuit prepared desired state with uniformly distributed values from $|000\rangle$ to $|100\rangle$.

---

**EDIT 2:** here is a code in QASM of the circuit above:

```
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";

qreg q[3];
creg c[3];

ry(0.927) q[0];

ry(pi/4) q[1];
cx q[0],q[1];
ry(pi/4) q[1];
cx q[0],q[1];

ry(pi/2) q[2];
cx q[1],q[2];
ry(-pi/4) q[2];
cx q[0],q[2];
ry(pi/4) q[2];
cx q[1],q[2];
cx q[0],q[2];

measure q[0] -> c[2];
measure q[1] -> c[1];
measure q[2] -> c[0];
```

Comment: If $m \neq 2^{n}$ for example $m=5$, what should be the approach?

Comment: @AdamLevine: Good question, see expanded answer.

Comment: Please share code for the above circuit

Comment: @AdamLevine: Please find it in the answer.

Comment: Dear Martin Vesely, following the paper - " Transformation of quantum states using uniformly controlled rotations." did you solve it by pen and paper? In paper, $|a\rangle \mapsto |e_{1}\rangle$ is given (this is not applicable for our transformation since it is already in $|e_{1}\rangle$ form), but how do I convert  $|e_{1}\rangle \mapsto |b\rangle$  (where $|b\rangle$ is the state we require)?

Comment: @AdamLevine: Yes, you are right that only conversion from $|e_1\rangle$ to $|b\rangle$ is important. Moreover, we are not interested in setting phase, so only $Ry$ rotation are necessary for our case. I did it as you said with "pen and paper" and I have to say that it is very easy to get lost in indices and sums. If you provide me with your e-mail address I will share Excel sheet I prepared for calculation of angles for $Ry$ gates. Note, that I did so only for 2 and 3 qubit states.

Comment: How did you convert $|e_{1}\rangle$ to $|b\rangle$? As per the paper, I can follow $B|b\rangle=|e_{1}\rangle$ and then finding hermitian conjugate of B? How did u do it in circuit? My email is cykbuzz@gmail.com

Comment: @AdamLevine: The main idea is to employ *unifromly controlled rotations* (i.e. rotations applied on a qubit controlled by another $n$ qubits where a rotation angle depends on combination of all qubits, the angle is different for different combination of controlling qubits). Application of these rotations on each qubit in state you prepare leads to desired superposition. Rotation angles of each gate used in circuit is calculated with equation (8) in the article (note coefficients $a_{i}$ are amplitudes in desired superposition). I have just sent you an e-mail with promised Excel sheet.

Answer (score 3):

The circuit you have described is formed of 2 qubits, both in an equal superposition. This can be achieved by applying the `H` gate to both qubits, as this puts each qubit into superposition and takes us up to 4 possible states. In the IBM Quantum Experience, this circuit would look like [image: 2 qubit superposition]